# JasperReports: spliting string value with delimiter

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a problem with *JasperReports*.  I am passing string values to a report. A specific code has included to each and every value that I’m passing, like “pre: 001”, “ab: 002”, “lv: 003”.

Codes - “pre”,”ab”,”lv”

As I mentioned above, each code and value can separately identify by “:” notation. 
In *Java* I used following code to separate the code and value;

```
a = “pre:001”;
String[] b = a.Split(“:”,2);
System.out.println(b[0]);  // code
System.out.println(b[1]);  // value
```

**Problem**

I need to pass combined value (code+value) to the report but the text field should only appear the value portion.

Ex:

Input – “pre:010”

Output-“010”

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. You already did what you want.

Comment: That should be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be in the `text field expression` for field `A`:

```
$F{A}.split(":",2)[1].trim()
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. It works. Another question, what is this ireporting language??.  I have to do many things in ireport. But I don’t know how and what I need to write inside the text field expression.
This is not java. But it is similar to java. Is there any tutorials??.

Comment: There is [Groovy](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/ireport-designer-groovy) in JasperReports.

Comment: Here's a simpler usage pattern (from link below):
`$F{Field}.split(":")[0] $F{Field}.split(":")[1]`
http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/510881/split-string

Answer (score 2):

To split a field 'fieldname' with '|' delimiter and get first element

```
$F{fieldname}.toString().split("\\|")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using irport add expression to your text field like {fieldName}.substring() from property menu.